# How to set selectedFilterOperation= 'startswith' on dxdatagrid?

Tags: angular, datagrid, devextreme

I set column in html file :

```
 <dxi-column selectedFilterOperation='startswith' dataField="currencyTypeFromName" caption="Kur Tipinden"></dxi-column>
```

and then, i saw my grid this change, it was be default 'startswith'. But this property is not working.. Contains is working, i try this  but i need to startswith. LoadOptions wasnt update.. My steps as this picture:

[image]

What can i do this issue?

Comment: could you provide a reproduction demonstrating your issue? Otherwise please show all the relevant files to get an idea. The image was helpful, but not quite to the extend required.

Comment: devextreme loadOptions always set default 'contains' option in selectedFilterOperations. I tried to set loadOptions.filter array but again only contains option run.

Comment: @amal i think actually only dxi column code clear up. that photo was only just a additional. maybe text was small on photo but issue is not this. if you know solve of my problem, please share your experience. thanks.

Comment: thanks for trying to clarify. In order to understand the problem better, it would be beneficial to have the relevant sections of your code if you are still struggling with this problem. Having said that, I have a feeling it might be due to the way you set this `searchOperation` value in your `loadOptions`. See [this](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/Data_Layer/DataSource/Methods/#searchOperationop) for how to set it using something like `dataSource.searchOperation("startswith")`.

Comment: `//grid Ds
        this.currencyRateDs = new DataSource({           
            load: (loadOptions) => {
                //loadOptions.searchOperation = loadOptions.filter ? "startswith" : null;
                loadOptions.userData = this.requestModel;              
                //debugger;
                return service.getCurrencyRateGridData(loadOptions).toPromise().then(response => response);
            }
        });`    i tried your advice, but doesn't work

Comment: in api: `public object GetCurrencyRateGridData(GetCurrencyRateGridData(GetCurrencyRateRequestModel request, DataSourceLoadOptions dataSource) {... ... return DataSourceLoader.Load(query2, dataSource); }`